# Pass application or acitivity context to service in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-activity, service, sip, android-context

Is it possible to pass my application context to my service running in android 2.3?

I am trying to make `WalkieTalkieActivity`  application as a service. But this application requires an application context, so is it possible to pass my application/activity context to this `walkieTalkie` service?

About [WalkieTalkieActivity](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html):
 a activity that login to SIP provider and registers the device to receive incoming SIP, handles incoming calls and makes outgoing calls, managing UI during the call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Service is already a Context: why do you need to pass anything to it?

Comment: You are correct, but if I try to pass the current context in following peice of code in WalkiTalkie service, it sends exception here is the code snippet where it fails:public void initializeManager() { if(manager == null) { manager = SipManager.newInstance(this); /* sends null pointer exception here */ } initializeLocalProfile(); }

Comment: Is it SIP manager issue? cannot we initialize sip manager if we use it as a service?

Comment: Well, looking at the SipManager javadoc (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html#newInstance%28android.content.Context%29) it says **the manager instance or null if SIP API is not supported**. Is the SIP api supported on your device? What is the result of `SipManager.isVoipSupported()` and `SipManager.isApiSupported()`? Do you have the `INTERNET` and `USE_SIP` permissions specified in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: i am able to run it on my google nexus if i make it as an activity. but if i try to run it as a service , then SIpManager.newInstaance(this) crashes.

Comment: Interesting: can you edit your post and add the code you are using from inside the service? There's nothing in the source that says you need to use an Activity context to make it work.